# can we redirect output of a batch file to a pdf file

Tags: windows-scripting, visual-sourcesafe-2005, batch-file

Is it possible to redirect the output of a batch file to a pdf file? I have a batch file that runs "ss diff" (source safe command to get the differences) on all the files in a project. Right now, it outputs the result to a text file. I was wondering if we can redirect the output to a text file. If not, is there a way to convert a text file to a pdf file automatically in a windows batch?

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Comment: I haven't used it, but this might help: http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/wpdos/converterscripts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one which I can use in the batch script

http://www.verypdf.com/txt2pdf/index.htm#dl

Answer (score 0):

You could run your batch file in PowerShell and pipe to Out-Printer, assuming you have a PDF "printer" installed.

```
PS C:\work> .\test.bat | out-printer "CutePDF Writer"
```